# Connect SQL Server with Yii framework

Tags: php, sql-server, yii, database-connection

I get this error when trying to use Yii framework with SQL Server 2019

[image]

I heard many people had this problem before so I installed the SQL Server drivers for PHP 7

[image]

PHP.ini:

[image]

And this is my php info:

[image]

The connection string:

[image]

I am using XAMPP server for running the application. Can somebody help me with my problem?

Edit: Removed the semicolons and got this

[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: Edit your `php.ini` and enable `php_pdo_sqlsrv_7_ts*.dll` extension. Restart the web server and check the output from `phpinfo()` - there must be a section `pdo_sqlsrv`.

Comment: I just removed the semicolons and restart the server and i got these two error for both extensions. The procedures entry point _zval_ptr_dtor could not be located in the dynamic link library and the procedure entry point _zend_hash_next_index_insert@@16 could not be located in the dynamic link library. See my new php.ini in the edited post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove semi colon with sqlsrv_7 extensions in .ini file
Restart server

Comment: I just removed the semicolons and restart the server and i got these two error for both extensions. The procedures entry point _zval_ptr_dtor could not be located in the dynamic link library and the procedure entry point _zend_hash_next_index_insert@@16 could not be located in the dynamic link library. See my new php.ini in the edited post